# Pretty way to code a bunch of similar if statements in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

i want to animate a sprite. To do that i have a ticker that gives me a time in milliseconds. Depending on the time i want the sprite to show a different image. Unfortunately i can't think of a simple and pretty way to do this except for a bunch of if statements.

```
    if (ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() >= ANIMATION_STEP * 0 &&
           ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() < ANIMATION_STEP * 1)
    {
        sprite_.setTexture(*game_->getResourceManager().getTexture("animation/explosion_00.png"));
    }

    if (ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() >= ANIMATION_STEP * 1 &&
           ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() < ANIMATION_STEP * 2)
    {
        sprite_.setTexture(*game_->getResourceManager().getTexture("animation/explosion_01.png"));
    }

    // 10 more of these ...

    if (ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() >= ANIMATION_STEP * 13 &&
           ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() < ANIMATION_STEP * 14)
    {
        sprite_.setTexture(*game_->getResourceManager().getTexture("animation/explosion_13.png"));
    }
```

Comment: Since the `if` statements differ only by multiplier, you could use a `for` loop.

Comment: Aside: assuming you have an event engine, rather than repeatedly (and probably redundantly) checking and setting which texture to use, just schedule an event for when you need to change to the next texture.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like

```
int frame = ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() / ANIMATION_STEP;
if (frame < MAX_FRAMES) {
    std::string filename = "animation/explosion_"
                         + std::to_string(frame) + ".png";
}
```

Comment: You need to convert the `int` to a string, and some `const` wouldn't hurt, but basically yes this.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the steps are even, you could just *compute* which one to use:

```
int step = ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() / ANIMATION_STEP;
```

You could do an integer-to-string conversion to use that to create the file-name, but that's both somewhat awkward to use and overly rigid. Instead, you could populate an array of filenames:

```
// populate array during program initialization 
vector<string> explosion_filenames;

// In your function,
sprite_.setTexture(*game_->getResourceManager().getTexture(explosion_filenames[step]));
```

or even better, an array of textures:

```
// populate array during program initialization 
vector<whatever_the_texture_type_is> explosion_textures;

// In your function,
sprite_.setTexture(*explosion_textures[step]));
```

If the steps aren't even, you could instead use an ordered map

```
// I use `int`, but use whatever type is most appropriate
// populate map during program initialization 
map<int, texture_type> explosion_textures;

// In your function,
int step = ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();
sprite_.setTexture(*explosion_textures.lower_bound(step)->second);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned frame = ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() / ANIMATION_STEP;
auto digit0 = std::to_string(frame % 10);
auto digit1 = std::to_string(frame / 10);
sprite_.setTexture(*game_->getResourceManager().getTexture("animation/explosion_"+digit1+digit0+".png"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
bool check(std::size_t step)
{
    auto tm = ticker_.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();
    return (tm >= ANIMATION_STEP * step) && (tm < ANIMATION_STEP * (step + 1));
}

for(int i=0; i <n;++i)
{
    if (check(i))
    {
        std::stringstream fname;
        fname<<"animation/explosion_"<<
        fname<<std::setfill(0)<<std::setw(2)<<i<<".png";
        sprite_.setTexture(*game_->getResourceManager().getTexture(fname.str()));
    }
}
```

Comment: That filename construction is pretty expensive

Answer (score 0):

Here is some oop like approach, which makes it easy to extend to a arbitrary number of animation_files.

It's just a quick'n'dirty prototype, but the scheme should be clear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

class AnimationManager
{
public:
    AnimationManager(float pStepsize) : mStepsize(pStepsize) {}
    void registerSprite(std::string pFilename) //assuming that animation files are registered in the right order, alternatively use std::map as backend or something else
    {
        mFilenames.push_back(pFilename);
    }
    std::string getFilenameForAnimationStep(float ellapsed_time)
    {
        if (ellapsed_time < 0) //we dont want go pack in the past
            ellapsed_time = 0;
        unsigned int step = static_cast<unsigned int>(ellapsed_time/mStepsize); //trunc to int
        step = std::min(step, mFilenames.size() - 1); //make shure we use the last registered animation, if we are to fahre in the future
        return mFilenames[step];
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> mFilenames;
    float mStepsize;
};




int main()
{
    AnimationManager my_manager(0.2);
    my_manager.registerSprite("step_0.jpq");
    my_manager.registerSprite("step_1.jpq");
    my_manager.registerSprite("step_2.jpq");
    my_manager.registerSprite("step_3.jpq");
    //....
    //testing
    std::cout << my_manager.getFilenameForAnimationStep(-0.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_manager.getFilenameForAnimationStep(0.1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_manager.getFilenameForAnimationStep(0.2) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << my_manager.getFilenameForAnimationStep(0.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_manager.getFilenameForAnimationStep(0.7) << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_manager.getFilenameForAnimationStep(1.7) << std::endl;

    system("Pause");
}
```